# Pandas - dealing with empty cells

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm having real difficulty using beautifulsoup to scrape the details of soccer players into a workable Pandas table.

The problem is some of the data that I scrape is "extra" and filling up rows of my table with nonsense. For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

HEADERS = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0"}

page = requests.get('https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/manchester-united/startseite/verein/985', headers=HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

playerdata = soup.find_all(class_='posrela')
names = [';'.join(pt.findAll(text=True)) for pt in playerdata]

df = pd.DataFrame(names)
df = pd.DataFrame([sub.split(";") for sub in names])

print(df.replace('^$', np.nan, regex=True))
```

Result:

```
 python testing5.py
                     0               1                   2                   3
0         David de Gea       D. de Gea              Keeper                None
1        Sergio Romero       S. Romero              Keeper                None
2         Joel Pereira      J. Pereira              Keeper                None
3          Eric Bailly       E. Bailly                             Centre-Back
4      Victor Lindelöf     V. Lindelöf         Centre-Back                None
5          Marcos Rojo         M. Rojo                             Centre-Back
6       Chris Smalling     C. Smalling         Centre-Back                None
7           Phil Jones        P. Jones                             Centre-Back
8          Daley Blind        D. Blind           Left-Back                None
9            Luke Shaw       Luke Shaw           Left-Back                None
10      Matteo Darmian      M. Darmian          Right-Back                None
11    Antonio Valencia     A. Valencia          Right-Back                None
12       Nemanja Matic        N. Matic  Defensive Midfield                None
13     Michael Carrick      M. Carrick                      Defensive Midfield
14          Paul Pogba        P. Pogba    Central Midfield                None
15       Ander Herrera      A. Herrera    Central Midfield                None
16   Marouane Fellaini     M. Fellaini    Central Midfield                None
17        Ashley Young        A. Young       Left Midfield                None
18  Henrikh Mkhitaryan   H. Mkhitaryan  Attacking Midfield                None
19           Juan Mata       Juan Mata  Attacking Midfield                None
20       Jesse Lingard      J. Lingard           Left Wing                None
21       Romelu Lukaku       R. Lukaku      Centre-Forward                None
22     Anthony Martial      A. Martial                   .      Centre-Forward
23     Marcus Rashford     M. Rashford      Centre-Forward                None
24  Zlatan Ibrahimovic  Z. Ibrahimovic                          Centre-Forward
```

As you can see, where I've scraped empty data, it has pushed data into the wrong cells. You may be asking why I have a 4th column, well I'm going to be inserting more data in there but for now I need to clean up column 3.

As you can see I've tried a regex to replace blanks with NaN in the first instance. But whatever I try, I can't seem to "select" the empty cells. I can't get to them!

When I try and treat 'names' like a list, I get told by the interpretor that this is not a list but a resultset!

Wondering if anyone can help, as a programming noob I've made a lot of progress but have hit a brick wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your going to extract more data, I suggest that you extract it all in an order that easily fits into the dataframe. You will continuously have to run unnecessary cleanup operations, unless you extract the data in the right format

```
playerdata = soup.find_all(class_='inline-table')

names = [[x.find('img')['title'],
         x.find_all(class_='spielprofil_tooltip')[-1].renderContents(),
         x.find_all('tr')[-1].find('td').renderContents()] for x in playerdata]

df = pd.DataFrame(names,columns=['Name','Short','Position'])


                  Name            Short            Position
0         David de Gea        D. de Gea              Keeper
1        Sergio Romero        S. Romero              Keeper
2         Joel Pereira       J. Pereira              Keeper
3          Eric Bailly        E. Bailly         Centre-Back
4      Victor Lindelöf      V. Lindelöf         Centre-Back
5          Marcos Rojo          M. Rojo         Centre-Back
6       Chris Smalling      C. Smalling         Centre-Back
7           Phil Jones         P. Jones         Centre-Back
8          Daley Blind         D. Blind           Left-Back
9            Luke Shaw        Luke Shaw           Left-Back
10      Matteo Darmian       M. Darmian          Right-Back
11    Antonio Valencia      A. Valencia          Right-Back
12       Nemanja Matic         N. Matic  Defensive Midfield
13     Michael Carrick       M. Carrick  Defensive Midfield
14          Paul Pogba         P. Pogba    Central Midfield
15       Ander Herrera       A. Herrera    Central Midfield
16   Marouane Fellaini      M. Fellaini    Central Midfield
17        Ashley Young         A. Young       Left Midfield
18  Henrikh Mkhitaryan    H. Mkhitaryan  Attacking Midfield
19           Juan Mata        Juan Mata  Attacking Midfield
20       Jesse Lingard       J. Lingard           Left Wing
21       Romelu Lukaku        R. Lukaku      Centre-Forward
22     Anthony Martial       A. Martial      Centre-Forward
23     Marcus Rashford      M. Rashford      Centre-Forward
24  Zlatan Ibrahimovic   Z. Ibrahimovic      Centre-Forward
25       Romelu Lukaku    Romelu Lukaku      Centre-Forward
26          Paul Pogba       Paul Pogba    Central Midfield
27     Anthony Martial  Anthony Martial      Centre-Forward
28     Marcus Rashford  Marcus Rashford      Centre-Forward
29         Eric Bailly      Eric Bailly         Centre-Back
```

Comment: Great answer, I did battle with beautifulsoup (like you have rightly suggested) to get the source data correct in the first place. Obviously I did not do too well! Not very good with selecting. However I suspect you are 100% correct that getting the source right in the first place is a far more efficient way of doing things, thanks.

Comment: @charliedontsurf, glad to help! Im sure you will have to scrap more data. If your using chrome i like to right click and click on inspect, greatest tool for websrcaping. You can work down the tree and highlight positions on the page. Then try and filter them with bs4 one level at a time :)

Comment: I have another question (I have made good progress!) but some of the items that I scape will return sometimes with a b' prefix and sometimes[b' ... ] 
I do not know why this is! I would like to cleanup the results before I proceed. I presume it is to do with the type of data I am scraping...

Answer (score 2):

You can use post processing - replace non `NaN` from column 3 to 2 column with `loc` and [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
df.loc[df[3].notnull(), 2] = df[3]
#remove column 3
df = df.drop(3, axis=1)
```

Another solution is with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df[2] = df[2].mask(df[3].notnull(), df[3])
df = df.drop(3, axis=1)
```

Or very similar with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df[2] = np.where(df[3].notnull(), df[3], df[2])
df = df.drop(3, axis=1)
```

I try a bit improve your solution:

```
playerdata = soup.find_all(class_='posrela')
names = [list(pt.findAll(text=True)) for pt in playerdata]
df = pd.DataFrame(names)
df.loc[df[3].notnull(), 2] = df[3]
df = df.drop(3, axis=1)
print (df)

                     0               1                   2
0         David de Gea       D. de Gea              Keeper
1        Sergio Romero       S. Romero              Keeper
2         Joel Pereira      J. Pereira              Keeper
3          Eric Bailly       E. Bailly         Centre-Back
4      Victor Lindelöf     V. Lindelöf         Centre-Back
5          Marcos Rojo         M. Rojo         Centre-Back
6       Chris Smalling     C. Smalling         Centre-Back
7           Phil Jones        P. Jones         Centre-Back
8          Daley Blind        D. Blind           Left-Back
9            Luke Shaw       Luke Shaw           Left-Back
10      Matteo Darmian      M. Darmian          Right-Back
11    Antonio Valencia     A. Valencia          Right-Back
12       Nemanja Matic        N. Matic  Defensive Midfield
13     Michael Carrick      M. Carrick  Defensive Midfield
14          Paul Pogba        P. Pogba    Central Midfield
15       Ander Herrera      A. Herrera    Central Midfield
16   Marouane Fellaini     M. Fellaini    Central Midfield
17        Ashley Young        A. Young       Left Midfield
18  Henrikh Mkhitaryan   H. Mkhitaryan  Attacking Midfield
19           Juan Mata       Juan Mata  Attacking Midfield
20       Jesse Lingard      J. Lingard           Left Wing
21       Romelu Lukaku       R. Lukaku      Centre-Forward
22     Anthony Martial      A. Martial      Centre-Forward
23     Marcus Rashford     M. Rashford      Centre-Forward
24  Zlatan Ibrahimovic  Z. Ibrahimovic      Centre-Forward
```

Another solution:

```
playerdata = soup.find_all(class_='posrela')

names = []
for pt in playerdata:
   L = list(pt.findAll(text=True))
   #check length of list
   if len(L) == 4:
      #assign 4. value to 3. 
      L[2] = L[3]
   #appenf first 3 values in list 
   names.append(L[:3])

df = pd.DataFrame(names)
```

---

```
print (df)
                     0               1                   2
0         David de Gea       D. de Gea              Keeper
1        Sergio Romero       S. Romero              Keeper
2         Joel Pereira      J. Pereira              Keeper
3          Eric Bailly       E. Bailly         Centre-Back
4      Victor Lindelöf     V. Lindelöf         Centre-Back
5          Marcos Rojo         M. Rojo         Centre-Back
6       Chris Smalling     C. Smalling         Centre-Back
7           Phil Jones        P. Jones         Centre-Back
8          Daley Blind        D. Blind           Left-Back
9            Luke Shaw       Luke Shaw           Left-Back
10      Matteo Darmian      M. Darmian          Right-Back
11    Antonio Valencia     A. Valencia          Right-Back
12       Nemanja Matic        N. Matic  Defensive Midfield
13     Michael Carrick      M. Carrick  Defensive Midfield
14          Paul Pogba        P. Pogba    Central Midfield
15       Ander Herrera      A. Herrera    Central Midfield
16   Marouane Fellaini     M. Fellaini    Central Midfield
17        Ashley Young        A. Young       Left Midfield
18  Henrikh Mkhitaryan   H. Mkhitaryan  Attacking Midfield
19           Juan Mata       Juan Mata  Attacking Midfield
20       Jesse Lingard      J. Lingard           Left Wing
21       Romelu Lukaku       R. Lukaku      Centre-Forward
22     Anthony Martial      A. Martial      Centre-Forward
23     Marcus Rashford     M. Rashford      Centre-Forward
24  Zlatan Ibrahimovic  Z. Ibrahimovic      Centre-Forward
```

Comment: Thanks - that has worked amazingly well. Now to get my head around it. I've used loc before for singling out "cells" but the rest will take some thinking. **Just noticed your edits, thanks once again.

Comment: Glad can help, also I a bit improve your solution and add another. Nice weekend!